# Hot swap Spring Beans in runtime

Tags: java, spring

I want to have possibility to swap spring bean in runtime. I found solution using HotSwappableTargetSource, but I am dissatisfied with this solution. When project will has 100 - 200 beans with posibility to hot swapping, I will have to implements the same HotSwappableTargetSources with Proxy. I am looking for more generic solution.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with examples

Comment: e.g. Admin may have the posibility send to application (e.g. REST ) Java source of particular class. Application will compile this source and will find bean by name and replace it.

Comment: Are you aiming to use such a *HotSwap* approach in production?

Comment: Don't exactly. I tried to give a simple example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of hot-swap.

### 1. Hotswap using the JPDA-Debugger throu the IDE (aka How-Code-Replace)

If you debug an class and like to immediately change the code without further actions to the lifecycle of the application. This is not possible for Spring-Beans (aka CDI-Beans). A workaround is to have a Spring-Bean like this:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
  private HotSwappable other = new HotSwappable();

  @Transactional
  public void notHotSwappable(){
    other.hotSwappableMethod();
  }
}
```

And the `HotSwappable`-class like

```
public class HotSwappable {
  public void hotSwappableMethod(){
    System.out.println("This output can be changed in runtime by debugger if connected.");
  }
}
```

You can change the contents of the `hotSwappableMethod`.

### 2. HotSwap of spring beans as part of the unattached and natural flow of the application

You can implement [HotSwappableTargetSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/HotSwappableTargetSource.html) to switch the implementations at runtime.

### 3. More generic

A more generic solution would be to use the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

> (...) represent part-whole hierarchies (...)